# only show container with next/prev links if they exist?

Tags: php, query, functions

hey guys,
i know there is something like 
`if ( function_exists('')`

is it possible to use that with `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()`.

The reason I'm asking that is that I have something like

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; older') ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('newer &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

In my case div.navigation has a colored background and a fixed height. So even there is no next or perv post this div.navigation appears. I wonder if I can only display this if there exists a next or prev post?

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link:
http://www.ericmmartin.com/conditional-pagepost-navigation-links-in-wordpress-redux/

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; older') ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('newer &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [(educational) "Easy Pagination Deamon" plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon). I reworked it for readability and it shows you all possibilities you got with pagination.